# Lotus Notes documents - Gets corrupt & Field Info Tab is empty

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I have a notes database and recently we are having an issue across random documents. Users gets error "**The linked document cannot be found in the view**" when they try to open a document from a view. I am not sure how to reproduce this issue.

I tried the below options to reproduce it, but no luck:

1. Attaching a document link to one of the Rich text field and deleting the link's target.
2. Attaching a file as a link and deleting the file in the target.

I am not seeing any pattern with the documents having the issue. The documents accessed few days ago, which was not accessed for more than 2 years also becomes corrupt like this.

Other details:

- The Field info tab in Document properties dialog box is empty
- There is no scheduled agent running overnight affecting this documents
- No change was done to the database recently
- We recently migrated to Notes 11.0 from 9.0

Since we have a daily backup of the database, we restore the document from one of the restored copy in which it was working fine.

Comment: Do all users have this issue for the same documents? Or is to only some users, and different docs for each user? Also, is it only the affected documents for which the fields tab is empty? Or is it empty for all documents?

Comment: If it happens for a document, all the users get the same error. Only for the affected documents, the field tab is empty. For the documents we are able to open, I can see the field Info as expected.

Answer (score 1):

A guess: did you try re-indexing the view? Shift-F9?

It could also be in the form, or even the view.
What if ...

- you open the same document from a different view?
- you remove some, many or all fields from the form, do you still see the error?

Comment: Yes, Rebuilding the view, removes the document completely from view. It doesn't display once we rebuild the view or run a maintenance in the dB.  Since the fields tab is already empty, I did not try removing the fields from the form. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

I think those documents have actually been deleted, and two things make me think that:

- You say in a comment that rebuilding the view makes the documents disappear. I'd expect this only if the documents no longer exist.
- I have in the past had LotusScript code doing view lookups which produced documents that I knew to be deleted, but the `NotesDocument.IsDeleted` property was `False` and the `NotesDocument.Items` property was `Empty` (i.e. no fields in the document). This is consistent with your saying the Field info tab is empty.

I'd check if any user action or code could delete documents. You say there are no scheduled agents, but maybe some user action could run code which deletes documents, or some users with the Delete privilege in the database ACL could be directly deleting documents using the Delete key on the keyboard.

Also check the database properties -> Info tab -> User Detail. This should show if there are recent deletions, but the record is probably limited to the last week or less.

Comment: Scott, To avoid User Deletion we removed the Delete Documents access for everyone in ACL including server ID. But still no luck. Also the User Activity tab does not show any entry for deletions when we have this issue.